# Java 7 support on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, java-7

How do I get Java 7 working on Heroku? Is there a buildpack somewhere?

I am looking at the default Heroku buildpack and don't have a clue on how to turn Java 7 on: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java

Cheers,
Owen

Comment: Have you tried java 7 and did not get the result?

Answer (score 5):

Add a system.properties file to your project, set java.runtime.version=1.7, and set your build pack to use the github URL you mentioned. More info here: https://gist.github.com/1b0a97fd1883ce752ce7

We're just now exposing this feature, so the docs aren't updated yet.

Comment: The docs have been updated and you don't need the buildpack any longer: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-java-version-to-an-existing-maven-app.